# Box which contains of another Box

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to achieve a layout like this:

[image: score image]

[Right Now image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQx7n.png)

My current code is as follows:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.weight(0.6f), 
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Row(
        modifier =
            Modifier.background(brush = color, shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        // Trying to add shadow and elevation here and my box getting cropped
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Card(
                modifier =
                    Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        .offset(y = (-15).dp)
                        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                        .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 5.dp),
                colors =
                    CardDefaults.cardColors(
                        containerColor = colorRedLive,
                    ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 2.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "Live",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    style = TextStyle(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary)
                )
            }
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.offset(y = (-10).dp).fillMaxWidth(),
                text = "3 - 5",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                style =
                    TextStyle(
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(600),
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                    )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

There is one Box with shadow and elevation. Inside that Box I have Card with Text "LIVE". 
I have done most of it but when I'm applying elevation and shadow, my Card with the "LIVE" text is getting chopped/cropped at the top.

How can I achieve the desired layout?

Comment: I edited your post and included the image you posted as a comment. Could you also edit your post and include an image that shows how your current solution with the cropping looks like?